# What resources could I link when reporting the definition of a word, or a phrase?

Tags: discussion, online-resources

What are the resources for which I could give a link when giving the definition of a word, or a phrase?

I usually use the definition given from the NOAD, OED, or the Merriam-Webster, which are accessible through an application on my computer/iPod, but I would like to refer a resource that is freely accessible to everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm copy-and-pasting a definition, I'll just do it the way you do, and simply cite NOAD.

If I want to paste a **link** to a specific definition, though, I'll usually use [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dictionary), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dictionary), or [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dictionary?q=dictionary). Those sites seem to be fairly "clean" and don't have too much heavy advertising. (I avoid M-W and Dictionary.com, because those sites seem more cluttered with advertising; M-W in particular will sometimes contain video ads that start playing after landing on the page.)

If I want to give a link to other dictionary links, I'll generally use [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=dictionary&ls=a) for that. And if I want to use a page that has definitions from more than one dictionary, I'll often use [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/dictionary).

Comment: +1 In my experience ODO usually provides the most examples, which are of particular value to our Learners, and uses the fewest abbreviations and ellipses, which are likely to be baffling to them.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the sources named by J.R. I suggest the [Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) (OALD), which provides somewhat fuller answers which take less for granted. For instance, here is the base definition of *afraid* from ODO:

> feeling fear or anxiety; frightened

And here is the base definition from OALD:

> feeling fear; frightened because you think that you might be hurt or suffer

Both provide copious examples, but the OALD carefully avoids using words and terms the Learner might not know.